# Converting a string to an array, alphabetizing, and then coverting back to a string

Tags: arrays, string

I am working on this problem and can't get my output file to show the whole string alphabetized from the input file.

My input file is:(no spacing in between the three lines)

eafcd

fghij

lk

The output file is:(no spacing in between the three lines)

fghij

lk

I believe the problem is in my alphabetize method but I cant seem to figure it out why some of the characters aren't appearing in the output file.

Thank you for your help!

using System;
using System.IO;

namespace TestFileIO
{
    class fileFileIO
    {
        private static string foo;

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        StreamWriter writer = null;

        writer = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Files\OutputWrite2.txt");
        Console.SetOut(writer);

        Console.SetIn(new StreamReader(@"C:\Files\InputRead2.txt"));
        string letters = Console.ReadLine();

        foo = alphabetize(letters);

        string line = foo;
        while ((line = Console.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            string newLine = line; 
            Console.WriteLine(newLine);
        }
        writer.Close();

        StreamWriter standardOutput = new StreamWriter(Console.OpenStandardOutput());
        standardOutput.AutoFlush = true;
        Console.SetOut(standardOutput);

        Console.WriteLine("Alphabetized all characters in requested file and wrote to output file.");

    }
    public static string alphabetize(string letters)
    {
        char[] line = letters.ToCharArray();
        Array.Sort<char>(line);
        return new string(line);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
while ((line = Console.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        string newLine = line; 
        Console.WriteLine(newLine);
    }
```

The Console.ReadLine() in the while condition is overwritting the contents of 'line' variable. This is reason why you are missing out on the first line of the input file

The following code should satisfy your requirements.

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        StreamWriter writer = null;

        writer = new StreamWriter(@"D:\OutputWrite2.txt");
        Console.SetOut(writer);

        Console.SetIn(new StreamReader(@"D:\InputRead2.txt"));
        string letters = Console.ReadLine();
        while (letters != null)
        {
            var foo = alphabetize(letters);
            string line = foo;
            string newLine = line;
            Console.WriteLine(newLine);
            letters = Console.ReadLine();
        }
        writer.Close();

        StreamWriter standardOutput = new StreamWriter(Console.OpenStandardOutput());
        standardOutput.AutoFlush = true;
        Console.SetOut(standardOutput);

        Console.WriteLine("Alphabetized all characters in requested file and wrote to output file.");

    }
    public static string alphabetize(string letters)
    {
        char[] line = letters.ToCharArray();
        Array.Sort<char>(line);
        return new string(line);
    }
```